# Print out all possible fixed length words

Tags: c++, stl, permutation

I want to print out all possible words (generating input for testing of other algorithm) of length `n`, containing the (maybe duplicated) letters from `'a'` to `'a' + n`.

I tried to do the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using size_type = std::size_t;
using symbol_type = std::string;
using char_type = typename symbol_type::value_type;

template< size_type n >
struct test
{

    static_assert(!(size_type('z' - 'a') + 1 < n));

    void
    print(symbol_type const & _symbol) const
    {
        for (size_type i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            std::cout << _symbol.substr(i * n, n) << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    bool
    operator () () const
    {
        symbol_type mishmash_;
        for (size_type i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            mishmash_.append(symbol_type(n, char_type('a' + i)));
        }
        print(mishmash_);
        while (std::next_permutation(std::begin(mishmash_), std::end(mishmash_))) {
            print(mishmash_);
        }
        return true;
    }

};

int
main()
{
    test< 3 > const test_{};
    if (test_()) {
        std::cout << "Succes!" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Failure!" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

But there are duplicates of words. How to achive the desired in most optimal way?

Comment: You don't need `next_permutation` as you already said that the letters may be duplicated.

Comment: @MohitJain I'm sure I need something similar to `next_permutation`, there is absence of similar functions in **STL** (except `random_suffle` in some sense). As you can see I prints out a substrings (length = `n`) of whole string (of length `n * n`), which contains `n` duplicates of each letter.

Comment: You are creating string `aaabbbccc` and printing first 3 characters of its permutation. You have no way to distinguish the strings when first 3 characters are same but rest are repeated. So you can work better without STL here. (Recursion and backtracking for example)

Comment: The desired is achiveable by means of `n` nested `for` loops.

Comment: You can achieve it with 1 for loop also. Or use `std::set` to keep a track of combinations already printed and don't print those again.

Comment: @MohitJain Using `std::set` is not optimal. Even `std::unordered_set` is bad due to additional memory using. I think there is much more simplier solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's conceptually the same task as iterating the numbers from 0000000... (n times) to 999999... - just doing a base-n conversion: i.e. increment a number and each time you want the next "value", use `% n + 'a'` to extract a "digit" and `/= n` to prepare to get the next one....

Answer (score 1):

You can write your test class as shown below.

```
struct test
{

    //static_assert(!(size_type('z' - 'a') + 1 < n));

    void
    print(symbol_type const & _symbol) const
    {
        std::cout << _symbol << std::endl;
    }

    bool
    operator () () const
    {
        symbol_type mishmash_(n, char_type('a' - 1));
        int cidx = 0;
        while (cidx >= 0) {
            if(cidx == n) {
                print(mishmash_);
                --cidx;
            } else {
                if(++mishmash_[cidx] == char_type('a' + n)) --cidx;
                else mishmash_[++cidx] = char_type('a' - 1);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

[Live example here](http://ideone.com/1I59gO)

Answer (score 0):

Following may help:

```
template <typename T>
bool increase(const std::vector<T>& v, std::vector<std::size_t>& its)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0, size = its.size(); i != size; ++i) {
        const std::size_t index = size - 1 - i;
        ++its[index];
        if (its[index] == v.size()) {
            its[index] = 0;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

template <typename T>
void do_job(const std::vector<T>& v, std::vector<std::size_t>& its)
{
    // Print example.
    for (std::size_t i = 0, size = v.size(); i != size; ++i) {
        std::cout << v[its[i]] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template <std::size_t N>
void test()
{
    std::vector<char> v(N);
    std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 'a');
    std::vector<std::size_t> its(N, 0);

    do {
        do_job(v, its);
    } while (increase(v, its));

}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/D9wtjK).